# Convert Object to string in firefox

Tags: javascript, json, firefox, stringify

I want to convert `Geo Location Position Object` into `String` so i can store it into `localStorage` for later use.

For now i did below methods

```
$.toJSON(position)
JSON.stringify(position) // position is the object which return from Geo Location Success callback
jQuery.stringify(position)
```

By using all above of these i can't get `String` in Firefox

Also checked this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042212/ff-13-ie-9-json-stringify-geolocation-object) but it didn't help as such

FireFox Console Result

[image]

Chrome Console Result

[image]

Demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/TLE33/11/) using `jQuery.stringify(position)`

Comment: Is `position` a object with contents?

Comment: yes it contains timestamps and co-ordinates of current position @Cerbrus

Comment: And you tried `localStorage.setItem('position', JSON.stringify(position));`?

Comment: Yes
In chrome it store while in firefox its store only `{}` this

Comment: So, it's an empty object. I suspect the geolocation api on your FF doesn't have access to the data...

Comment: i checked through `for(key in position)...` it shows data but every plugin that i use to comvert into string it gives me empty string like `{}`

Comment: And `console.log(position)` logs a normal geolocation object?

Comment: yes it show correctly

Comment: @Cerbrus i update question with console output image and `jsFiddle` demo

Comment: I'm pretty stumped. I've got no clue why the properties aren't passed... Can you try `.stringify(position.timestamp)`?

Comment: `.stringify(position.timestamp)` it showed just time stamp in console.

Comment: Hm, what if you create a temporary object, copy the properties from the location object to the temp one, then stringify the temp one?

Comment: `var newPosition = position;`   like this??

Answer (score 2):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042212/ff-13-ie-9-json-stringify-geolocation-object) explains why this is happening in FF but not in Chrome.

As a workaround you could do:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var myPosition={timestamp: position.timestamp,
                    latitude:position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude:position.coords.longitude,
                    altitude:position.coords.altitude,
                    ...
                    }
    localStorage.position=JSON.stringify(myPosition);

});
```