# isolate scope angular binding not updated from geolocation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, navigator, isolate-scope

I'm using isoated scope in a directive.  Everything seems to work fine.  I set a `=` scope on two properties and bind to them in my template.  Then, in my controller I call my service, get the data and push it onto the bound objects.

What is really wigging me out is that I can both log and set a break point and can see the data, but angular doesn't update the binding (although it updates my bool field just fine).

I've provided a plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/8sVwaea5Amqvf3yiI1Nm?p=preview

And the relevent code portion is:

```
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
    $timeout(function() { success({testdata: "bogusdata"}) }, 1500);
  } else {
    fail({ error: "navigator.geolocation not available"});
  }
```

Clearly, if I use my $timeout mock, it works just fine.  But if I substitute the getCurrentPosition function, nothing updates (but it DOES LOG)?!?!

Help?

Comment: Excellent code. I'm trying to find any issue or bug to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you only have a problem with the way you're trying to handle the data - the Geolocation object arrives and gets put on the `$scope` correctly, it's only that `JSON.stringify` serializes it (seemingly incorrectly) into a `{}`.

You can verify this by logging `$scope.locationData.payload` - you will see the entire object appear on the console, and logging `typeof $scope.locationData.payload.coords` shows `object`, which means that it is populated properly at the time of the log call. *(Logging the object itself would not be proof of this, because console.log is only logging object references, asynchronously accessing them when you expand them manually)*

This is only seemingly incorrect, because `JSON.stringify` is only supposed to log the own properties of an object, and `coords` and `timestamp` are not own properties of this Geolocation object. *(try `$scope.locationData.payload.hasOwnProperty('coords')`: it returns `false`)*

The workaround will depend on your exact needs. Maybe you don't even need a workaround, because you can access this data, just can't log or stringify it the way you wanted.

Additional resources:

- Here's a blog article I found which came across the same problem: [Beware of JSON.stringify](http://www.allannienhuis.com/archives/2015/02/04/beware-json-stringify/)
- Here's a stackoverflow post explaining why these properties are not *own* properties of Geolocation: [JSON stringify / Geolocation object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042212/ff-13-ie-9-json-stringify-geolocation-object)

Comment: Thanks for the response, it will take me a bit to digest it.

Comment: Try to get single properties from location data object: $scope.locationData = { message: error.message... }