# object not sent in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have the following code

```
$locationButton.onclick = () => {
    if(!navigator.geolocation) { return alert('method unavailable'); }
    $locationButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position)
        $locationButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
        socket.emit('USER:SEND_LOCATION', position, (response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    })
}
```

and on server

```
socket.on('USER:SEND_LOCATION', (position: any, callback: Function) => {
    console.log(position)
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    socket.broadcast.emit('SERVER:NEW_LOCATION', {position, timestamp, user: 'Me'});
    callback({position, timestamp, user: 'Me'});
})
```

The problem I have is, in client, there is a position object on the first console.log, then I try send it do the server, and the server always get only an empty object instead '{}'

I tried json.strigify, but I sill get a '{}'

Comment: What does the `position` object/whatever looks like?

Comment: the one in node js ? just an empty object {}

Comment: Not on the node side, on the client side... What do you see when you do `console.log(position)` after calling `getCurrentPosition()`?

Comment: the Position object of chrome

Comment: Got it, have a look at the solution below

Comment: Let me know if this solved your issue. If so, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I have not got the time to come back to this project yet, but I will keep you update and update the solution when I do. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the `position` object/result that you get from calling `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is that it's properties are not enumerable, meaning that you can't easily "stringify" the object and pass it along with your `socket.emit` call, which is why you're getting an empty object as a result.

Although you can write a function that will extract these properties for you, you could do the following:

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
  const payload = {
    coords: {
      accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
      altitude: position.coords.altitude,
      altitudeAccuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
      heading: position.coords.heading,
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      speed: position.coords.speed
    },
    timestamp: position.timestamp
  }
  socket.emit('USER:SEND_LOCATION', JSON.stringify(payload))
})
```

Then, on your server side, you can do the following:

```js
socket.on('USER:SEND_LOCATION', (position, callback) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(position)

  console.log(data) // { coords: {...}, timestamp: ... }
})
```

---

If you'd like a little cleaner solution, have a look at this function that will take the `position` object and turn it into an object that can be easily "stringified":

- [FF 13, IE 9: JSON stringify / geolocation object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726654/5862900)